# Accessing the CSS and HTML on wordpress version 4.8.1

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having a hard time trying to access my CSS & HTML files on my WordPress blog.

I posted a screenshot of what I CAN access, but it's not super straight forward,

However, I need to get into these settings so that I can change the display settings or screen dimensions?

My issue is that whenever someone goes onto my webpage: RobertNolfiRoofing.com 
and they resize the window- it moves my content all around. What I want is a fixed setting so that if someone were to resize the browser window it would have a scroll bar, rather than moving content around.

Thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHCPz.png)

Comment: a better option is trought ftp

Comment: note: WordPress version 4.8.1 using the theme astrid - use the plugin Elementor for customization

Comment: you must, know the wordpress structer to modify it, because every type of page is generated with deferents php file

Comment: You should be creating a child theme if you are going to make any changes to any of the theme's files, otherwise you will mess up your work when you update it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress 4.8.1, you can use (in almost any theme) the "Customizer" to *add* your own CSS: In the backend dashboard, choose menu *Design > Customizer*, which opens the customizer in a column at the left side. There, the last line is "custom CSS", where you can add CSS rules which either are additional or can overwrite existing CSS.

Comment: Johannes: do you have a suggestion in regards to my issue what I could add in the custom CSS so that a scroll bar is implemented onto my site when the window is resized?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but that's a responsive website which places elements below each other and fits them into the viewport width, which on a desktop are placed next to each other. That is the usual way responsive websites work. If you don't like that, you can start with erasing the line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">` from the HTML code (most likely in the `header.php` file, but in general that's not a good idea...

Comment: I see. How do you gain access to the HTML code via wordpress? Would I go to the website where I created my domain? I'm sorry I'm very ignorant to all this stuff- I just know how to word everything and customize.

Comment: sorry, but from the way you describe this, I would not recommend to try editing the HTML code - you really have to know what you are doing when you start that...

Comment: Okay well in regards to the custom CSS option that I have...what do you recommend I should plugin in order to stop content mushing all around when the window is resized?